# java/swing: drag and drop with a list of strings

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

What data flavor should I use to transfer a list of strings? I guess I can serialize the list of strings in JSON format, but was hoping I could just transfer a List directly.

Comment: Do you need to drag and drop between different applications or only within a single application?

Comment: hmm... I think just within, but I'm not 100% positive.

Comment: Are we talking swing or webapp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Java Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/dataflavor.html)

For example, to create a data flavor for the java.util.ArrayList class:

```
   new DataFlavor(ArrayList.class, "ArrayList");
```

[Transferring Data across the JVM boundary](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/dragndrop/spec/dnd1.html#wp922676)

Comment: +1 (for, among other reasons, finding an official Sun document that uses the phrase "bass-ackwards" regarding Microsoft's OLE :-)

Comment: Hmm... is there a way to signify ArrayList<String> vs. just plain ArrayList?

Comment: @Jason S I'm afraid that's not possible since it is defined like this:public DataFlavor(Class<?> representationClass, String humanPresentableName)

Comment: well, that's OK: at least I can use "humanPresentableName" to encode template parameter in string form, if not in a type-safe way.